# Pdfviewer not working in vim-r-plugin (windows 10)

Tags: gvim

I cannot seem to make the pdfviewer work in the vim-r-plugin in windows 10. 
I use acrobat, and have added the reader to the path. It works with latexsuite, as I use

```
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'AcroRd32'
```

in vimrc with no problem.

However, when I try to add

```
let vimrplugin_pdfviewer = 'AcroRd32'
```

to vimrc, I get an error message:

```
Error detected while processing function ROpenPDF:
line 41:
```

I tried installing sumatrapdf (and add it to the path) and keep vimrc clean and also using sumatra as an option in vimrc.

I also looked through the windows.vim and common_global.vim and as far as I can see my vimrc-options should be caught by the plugin. But to be sure I tried manually adding let g:rplugin_sumatra_path and let g:rplugin_pdfviewer = 'Sumatra' to my vimrc.

Any suggestions as to where I should look next?